# Order multiple items using PayPal in android

Tags: android, paypal

I am using PayPal in my android application. when i order single item the App works well. but when i add multiple items to cart and press the order button the app crashes. My problem is how can i pass multiple items and its details to PayPal to order it. For this, my piece of code is.

```
String price = res.getString("FoodPrice");
totalprice = totalprice + Integer.parseInt(price);
String title = res.getString("FoodTitle");
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(res.getString("quantity"));
PayPalItem ppi = new PayPalItem(title, quantity,
                        new BigDecimal(price), "USD", "sku");
    ppis = new PayPalItem[length];
    ppis[i] = ppi;

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    PayPalPaymentDetails pd = new PayPalPaymentDetails(
                            PayPalItem.getItemTotal(ppis), // price
                            new BigDecimal(10.0), // shipment costs
                            new BigDecimal(0));
                    thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(
                            totalprice), "USD", "shortDescription",
                            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
                    thingToBuy.items(ppis);
                    thingToBuy.paymentDetails(pd);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(FoodActivity.this,
                            PaymentActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra(
                            PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,
                            config);
                    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,
                            thingToBuy);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the example provided [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/SampleActivity.java#L109) for using optional payment details and item list.

```
    private PayPalPayment getStuffToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
    //--- include an item list, payment amount details
    PayPalItem[] items =
        {
                new PayPalItem("sample item #1", 2, new BigDecimal("87.50"), "USD",
                        "sku-12345678"),
                new PayPalItem("free sample item #2", 1, new BigDecimal("0.00"),
                        "USD", "sku-zero-price"),
                new PayPalItem("sample item #3 with a longer name", 6, new BigDecimal("37.99"),
                        "USD", "sku-33333") 
        };
    BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);
    BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("7.21");
    BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("4.67");
    PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(shipping, subtotal, tax);
    BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(amount, "USD", "sample item", paymentIntent);
    payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);

    //--- set other optional fields like invoice_number, custom field, and soft_descriptor
    payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

    return payment;
}
```